# Why isn't the $E$-field between two infinite charge sheets zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

The $E$-field due to an infinite positive charge sheet is perpendicular to the sheet and constant everywhere, pointing away from the sheet. If I add another sheet in front of this sheet with the same charge, the $E$-field due to the sheet should be the same exact as the first sheet, but in the opposite direction.

The sum of the $E$-fields would be 0 since they cancel out. But according to gauss law, the $E$-field is none zero. Why is this?

Comment: Can you walk through how you are applying Gauss's law here?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made an error. But I still find the same mistake when two sheets of opposite charges. Using gauss law, you can draw a cylinder that one of the sheets goes through. Charge around circle area is equal to total flux. Since no flux is around the cylinder. And e-feild is 0 on the top part of the cylinder. only the bottom circle has flux. So e-feild between the sheets is density/E0. However this is the same e-feild due to one sheet. How come the second sheet (which is suppose to pull/push in the same direction) adds no extra force ?

Comment: @LameloBall Your mistake is assuming the electric field is zero on the top part of the cylinder.

Comment: Why wouldn't it ? For two opposite charged sheets, if you not in between them, then the one is pulling and one is pushing with the same exact force (since e-feild doesn't change with distance for a infinite sheet) so its e-feild would then be 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be careful about how you use Gauss' law. Gauss' law only relates  the total flux coming out of a closed surface with the enclosed charge. That's not the same thing as telling you the electric field.

The electric field from two identical sheets of charge would indeed be 0 between the sheets, and doubled outside the sheets.